# Looping through a serialized sortable table

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm sending some serialized data to a PHP script via AJAX:

HTML:

```
<table class="mytable">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="item_01">
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="item_02">
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="item_03">
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="item_04">
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="item_05">
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$( '.mytable tbody' ).sortable({
    update: function() {
        items = $( this ).sortable( 'serialize' );
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { action: 'foo', items }
            cache: false,
            error: function() {
                console.log( 'Error' );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
if ($action == 'foo') {
    $items = $_POST['items'];
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++ ) {
        .....
    }
}
```

I had the impression that one could loop through the `$_POST['items']` var without any conversion, but I'm getting the serialized data instead:

```
item[]=val_1&item[]=val_2&item[]=val_3& ... &item[]=val_n
```

How can I loop through this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is with the way you post the items in your ajax call: the "serialize" function returns a *string* not an object. So you'll want to keep adding post data to the string as in:

```
...
data: 'action=foo&' + items // items is a string of the form "item[]=content&item[]=content..."
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried this, but the `$_POST['items']` var still contains the serialized data, not a PHP array. Maybe the fact I'm adding the `action` var to the `data` setting in the AJAX request is altering the whole thing.

Comment: Doh - you are right. Serialize returns a string, so you won't be able to use it directly as an object for posting. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out and provide us with specific of solution you need out of solution within links:

[How do I PHP-unserialize a jQuery-serialized form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792603/how-do-i-php-unserialize-a-jquery-serialized-form)

I've made your code preview on c9.io and it's working fine. Try to make external ajax.php with code like that:

```
<?php
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    if ($action == 'foo') {
        $items = $_POST['items'];

        parse_str($_POST['items'], $params);
        var_dump($params);
    }
?>
```

And make something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var items = $('.mytable tbody').sortable();
  items = items.sortable('serialize');

  var ajaxRequest = function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        action: 'foo',
        items
      },
      cache: false,
      complete: function(data){
        console.log(data)
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log('Error');
      }
    });
  };

  setInterval(function(){
    ajaxRequest();
  }, 2000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table class="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="item_01">
      <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="item_02">
      <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="item_03">
      <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="item_04">
      <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="item_05">
      <td>content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Check your console and browser request timeline and you will see array of unnamed keys [0..n] with values returned by your script.

Check this link for explanation how to work with this values:

[jQuery UI sortable not serializing with custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839235/jquery-ui-sortable-not-serializing-with-custom-attributes)